# How to C++11 static_assert for type constraint?

Tags: c++11, type-constraints, static-assert

How can I make `static_assert` for specific type constraint?

Currently I want to make my template only for `unsigned int` type, but not `signed int` type. Or, just only for integral type, or specific type names. `static_assert(sizeof(int))` offers only size based assertion, and I don't know how to perform any extra checks.

I am using Clang with its `libc++` in Xcode 4.6.2. Here's current compiler information on command-line.

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Note - Here is a list of possible type constraints: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not really what `static_assert` is for, but you can do it like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value, "bad T");
};
```

Or, if you just want `T` to be an unsigned integral type of some sort (not specifically `unsigned int`):

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
  static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "bad T");
};
```

Comment: static_assert requires a string second argument -- I went ahead and added them just so nobody's led slightly astray.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

To check for **all** integral types, the following can be used:

```
#include <type_traits>
// [...]
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "The type T must be an integral type.");
// [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scaffold:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TNum>
struct WrapNumber
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<TNum>::value, "Requires unsigned type");
    TNum num;
};

WrapNumber<unsigned int> wui;
WrapNumber<int> wi;
```